Doubt regarding finding analyticity of a function
Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function. Then which of the following are true?
(a) If $f$ is one-one, then $f(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$
(b) If $f$ is onto, then $U=\mathbb{C}$
(c)
If $f$
is onto, then $f$
is one-one.
(d)
If $f(U)$
is closed in $\mathbb{C}$
then $f(U)$
is connected.
This question has been discussed in the following link below. I would like to clarify option d alone. I tried taking 3 open  balls  $B1$ , $B2$, $B3$  such that $f(B1)=2$ , $f(B2)=3$, $f(B3)=4$ where $B1,B2,B3$ are disconnected and whose union is $U$. The image here is closed and disconnected contradicting option (d) but the problem is I don't know if $f$ is analytic or not.
Analytic function on an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{C}$
Kindly explain if $f$ is analytic or not and if not , then please provide some other counter example.

Your balls are necesasrily disjoint and  the $f$ is analytic on their union (by defintion of differentiabilty).

So it is enough to check for analyticity in eadh open connected set. Thanks a lot
